# ¿Es posible modificar options(--headless) de driver firefox en Selenium - Python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Inicio selenium con driver Firefox en python de esta forma:

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = Firefox(options=options,executable_path=xxxxxx)
```

Será posible modificar en ejecución los parámetros de Options? es decir por ejemplo el parámetro `--headless`, digamos pasando unos 5 min y el driver se ponga en segundo plano sin necesidad de levantar de nuevo todo.
Gracias

Comment: Hola. El `headless` es una opción usada al momento del crear el driver, no creo que se pueda usar dinámicamente.

Comment: Gracias por responder @cesar, tienes algún fundamento de ello?